# Proof spectral radius less than $1$

Tags: spectral-radius

Given that matrix $A$ is set as:
$A=(I-P)(I-QP)^{-1}$ 
where matrix $QP$ is non-negative reducible hollow matrix, and $\rho(QP)<1$. Matrix $P$ is a diagonal matrix and all entries in $P$ are in interval $[0,1]$
I am trying to proof that the spectral radius $\rho(A)<1$. I used Neumann Series to rewrite the matrix $(I-QP)^{-1}$ as
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(QP)^k$, then I am stuck here. How could I proof that the spectral radius of matrix $A$ is less than $1$? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Which definition of a hollow matrix are you using? Wikipedia gives a few different ones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix).

Comment: I use this definition "square matrix whose diagonal elements are all equal to zero".

Comment: there's a lot that seems off in this post.  I think you mean "irreducible" not "reducible" -- there's little reason to consider the latter.  You also must mean $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(QP)^k$ for the Neumann series.  Let $P:= \frac{1}{2}I$  and let $Q:= \alpha(J-I)$ where $J$ is the one's matrix.  With suitable choice of positive $\alpha$ we can make the spectral radius of $QP = \lambda$, the Perron root, arbitrarily close to $1$. Then $(I-QP)^{-1}$ has Perron root  $\frac{1}{1-\lambda}$ and $A$ has spectral radius  $\frac{1}{2(1-\lambda)}\gt 1$ for $\lambda$ close enough to 1

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the typo in the Neumann series. But the matrix QP is reducible, and another condition is all entries in P are in interval [0,1].

Comment: (1) My counter-example **still** works.  (2)  reducibles decompose (*i.e. reduce*) into blocks of irreducibles and hence for spectral purposes it is both necessary and sufficient for your claim to work on irreducibles.  It fails, see (1).  Focusing on a reducible matrix is a distraction.  Any decent book on markov chains will take this approach.  If you don't understand this you can still take my example and stick it in a block diagonal matrix as one of the blocks, then get a counter-example.